# Fails at setting codegen into CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

when setting codegen on Entities(Tag, Note, Category) in Data Model on Category/Extension and module 'Current Product Module'
[image]

then I get  20 errors
[image]

errors open this hidden from project file:
[image]
My Core Data Model:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyQGm.png)

I reading a book "mastering core data with swift" by Cocoacasts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the code generation to "category/extension", Xcode will not create a class for the entity, only a category or extension. If you use this type of generation, you **must** create a class. Xcode will only generate the extension, and if you don't create your own, then it's extending a nonexistent class. If you want to use this style of code generation, you need to create the class yourself.

If you set the code generation to "class definition", Xcode creates the class.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the errors, you should set codegen on Entities(Tag, Note, Category) in Data Model on Manual/None

Comment: but I should set it on Category/Extension